# Java Regex - remove remaining portion of sting after a math operator

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I need a regular expression that will remove the remaining characters after an operator.
User passes in an equation, ex 55-6  OR  55+6 OR ( * / ).

Just need a regex that reads until one of those characters are hit, and remove the rest.

Ive got the divide '/' figured out: `x = input.replaceAll("/[^/]*$", "");` 
I try following this same convention, but it doesnt work.

I looked at some of the other questions, but they all rely on knowing the specific character. In this case, I dont know what operator the user will pass in.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
x = input.replaceAll("[-|\\+|\\*|/].*$", "");
```

this expression looks for a  '-' OR '+' OR '*' OR '/', then removes everything after with the .*$   the | pipe is used to separate values.

the + and * characters actually mean something with regex, so the \  must be used before to show that you want the character itself.

Hopefully the detailed solution helps

Comment: I feel like either | (vertical line) symbols are redundant or you wanted to use ( ) (round braces) instead of [ ] (square braces). Am I missing something?

Comment: with the brackets[], you could go without the  ' | '.   With the parenthesis(), it seemed to only work when the ' | ' was there. 

I find it easier to read and follow along with, when the brackets[] and pipe | are together. It may be redundant, but easy to read.

Comment: But won't "[a|b]" in addition to "a" and "b" also match "|" in java? This is probably not a problem for this particular case, but could be an issue in another situation.

Comment: ah I see what you are saying. I suppose that is the case. With my example above, it will remove everything after and including the characters :  '-'   '+'   '*'   '/'   AND   '|'  . Good catch! remove the | and all should be good.

Answer (score 0):

You could combine them all into one regex although it gets a little messy.

For the divide you could replace it with this input.replaceAll("/.*$","");

Each one after that should be different because the signs are used in a regex. Therefore you have to escape them by putting a '\' before them. For the other three replace the first character with the \*,\+,\-.

Comment: It works fine with '/' but not with anything else

                x = input.replaceAll("-.*$", "");
  x = input.replaceAll("\\+.*$", "");
  x = input.replaceAll("\\*.*$", "");
  x = input.replaceAll("/.*$", "");

That is what I have after your comment. only works with '/'